# Using the onUpdate function in firebase, how do I pass in information from the front end?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So basically, I have a function that sends a user an email when a room Status becomes "Available"

```
exports.sendAvailableRoomEmail = functions.firestore.document('rooms/{roomId}/Status').onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    const newVal = snap.after.data();

    const oldVal = snap.before.data();

    if(newVal == "Available"){
        // send email
    }
})
```

what I need passed into the function is the specific room that the user wants a notification from: `{roomId}`

How can I pass that specific room only when the user clicks the notify me button right next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers for a Cloud Function needs to be known when you deploy that function. That means you can either trigger for all rooms, or you can trigger for a specific room, but you can't trigger for rooms that meet a dynamic condition such as yours.

The common way to implement the use-case is to query Firestore *inside* the Cloud Functions code to find if any user need to be notified for the specific room that was updated.

Comment: So would I just create a field in the user database basically "subscribing" the user to the specific room? & can I subscribe the user to an array of rooms so it only occurs when any of those rooms get updated?

Comment: "it only occurs" is a bit unclear there, but you'll indeed have to store the rooms that the user wants to be notified for and then query that in your Cloud Function when it triggers.

Comment: so how would I go about this in terms of code. can i just call {roomId} and see if it equals the users subscribed rooms?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the room ID from the path? You can get that from `context.params.roomId`, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters. You can then use that value in a query as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: so I got the roomID using the `const room = context.params.roomId` and now I'm struggling to check if the user has that room in his document. I did `const userRef = db.collection('users');` and `const queryRef = userRef.where('favroom', '==', room);` what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: These are all valid questions, but hard to cover in comments. If you can't get it working, I recommend posting a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the query. I recommend trying to reproduce the problem outside of Cloud Functions in that case, as isolating the problem makes it more likely that someone can help.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your help. I think I got it to work now. I was forgetting the `.get()` at the end of my query, then separating the `doc.data()` into all of the users information. It works now :)